# Prevent streaming VLC video over VNC session in linux

Tags: linux, video, vnc, vlc-media-player

I have one media dedicated computer directly connected to a TV which is used to watch movies. This computer is being remote controlled with VNC from a laptop.

The media computer used to have Windows XP and run RealVNC server, playing the video with VLC 2.0.x, and while the video was playing, the VNC client would only display a black screen where the video was being played, making it easy to control the interface without lags etc. This without any special settings being set, just worked as such out of the box.

Now however I've reinstalled the media pc with Debian Squeeze(backports), running VLC 1.1.3 and x11vnc Server 0.9.10, and now I don't seem to be able to make it do the same, the video is being transmitted back to the VNC client making the connection slow and difficult.

Does anyone know any tricks to stop the video stream from being transmitted to the VNC client?

Comment: Control the remote computer over ssh?

Comment: Not sure there's a way to control a VLC session (play, pause, fastforward etc) via the terminal. Either way it would be a lot more convenient to just do it over VNC.

Comment: True, true. I guess your right.

Answer (score -1):

Use the VLC built in http: interface.  I think it would do everything you want, and it's very quick.

Comment: Could you maybe expand your answer a little and explain how to achieve what the OP wants in more than one sentence?